# Adding new entities into Core Data without deleting previous version to avoid app crash

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, crash, entities

Hi I am iOS beginner and having CoreData implemented in my app.

Everytime I added new entities in my coredata, I need to re-create the NSManagedObject subclass, clean project, delete the existing app with previous core data and rebuild the app.

I'm thinking that what if my app is v1.0 and available in AppStore, user download and use the app. After few months I added new entities in Core Data (app v2.0), and user need to update their app. Are they needed to delete and re-download the new version to avoid app crash?

I found out someone mentioned that "You can configure core data to look for, and accept extensions of your data model" but I don't know what it means.
[Here is the question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7123096/1371949)

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the programming guide [**`Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration`**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html)

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer: "**Provide context for links** A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there."